# How to pass a derived class property to the constructor of a base class

Tags: c#, inheritance

Here's my base class:

```
class baseClass
{
 string fileContents; 

 public baseClass(string filePath)
 {
  fileContents=getContents(filePath);
 }

}
```

I have a derived class where the file path will always be the same.  Ideally I would like to pass that file path as follows:

```
class derivedClass:baseClass
{
 string specialFilePath=@"x:\abc.def";

 public derivedClass():base(specialFilePath)
 {
 }
}
```

But this gives me a compile error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'derivedClass.specialFilePath'
```

If I understand correctly, this is happening because the `baseClass` constructor gets called first, before `derivedClass` has a chance to create `specialFilePath`.  How can I pass this string back to the base class' constructor?

Comment: make it static string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make "specialFilePath" static, and this will work -- static members are initialized before the constructors run.

```
class derivedClass:baseClass
{
    static string specialFilePath=@"x:\abc.def";

    public derivedClass():base(specialFilePath)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might not even need a field if you do something like this.

```
class derivedClass : baseClass
{
    public derivedClass()
        : base(@"x:\abc.def")
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because at the time when you want to access to your property `specialFilePath`, it hasn't been initialized. Make it static.